# How does buildx name its pods when used with Kubernetes driver

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, buildx

I am trying to understand a problem that currently arises with `buildx`, its Kubernetes driver, GitLab CI/CD, and parallel jobs. What is the suffix `0` that appears in builder instances's pod names?

It looks like an index, but seems unrelated to replicas. For instance I tried this (notice the suffix `0` behind `test` and before the first hyphen):

```
$ docker buildx create --name test --driver kubernetes --driver-opt namespace=ci,replicas=2 --use
$ echo "FROM scratch" | docker buildx build -
$ kubectl get pod -n ci
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test0-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx 1/1     Running   0          xxxxx
test0-yyyyyyyyyy-yyyyy 1/1     Running   0          yyyyy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to nodes. By default, `docker buildx create` creates [a single node](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/#work-with-builder-instances). After creating a new builder, you can also append new nodes to it.

The relevant code is in [store/nodegroup.go](https://github.com/docker/buildx/blob/master/store/nodegroup.go#L138):

```
func (ng *NodeGroup) nextNodeName() string {
    i := 0
    for {
        name := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", ng.Name, i)
        if ii := ng.findNode(name); ii != -1 {
            i++
            continue
        }
        return name
    }
}
```

`docker buildx ls` lists all builders with their respective node(s).